# How do you get the rounded corner, gradient-polish iOS icon image effect with imagemagick?

Tags: ios, imagemagick

Given a square image, how can you get the iPhone icon effect using ImageMagick's tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago i used this: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/36477/iconifer

And found this code but its RMagic, maybe you can use it as a guide to port it.
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=13140&start=0#p44179

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I would use the same method iTunes does. Put a gloss overlay image onto the icon and then mask it. You can find both the gloss and mask images inside iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/iTunes.rsrc file (right click on iTunes icon and click Show package contents to get there). You can use [File Juicer](http://echoone.com/filejuicer/) to extract the images from this file.

Answer (score 0):

May refer to this tutorial from imagemagicks. This technique uses gray canvas image to create masked lighting effect. This pretty much create iOS alike icon. 
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#badge_lighting